# Finding $a+b+c+d$, where $ab+c+d=15$, $bc+d+a=24$, $cd+a+b=42$, $da+b+c=13$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations, groebner-basis

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following constraints:

\begin{cases} ab+c+d=15 \\ bc+d+a=24 \\ cd+a+b=42 \\da+b+c=13 \end{cases}

Calculate the value of $a+b+c+d$.

It is easy to use the Gröbner basis to get the value:

\begin{cases}
10849-4501 d+380d^2,-39409+2320c+3420d,-20+29b-9d,1801+2320 a-380 d\}
\end{cases}

so the value of $a+b+c+d$ is $\frac{169}{10}$.

What I am curious about is how to use high schools mathematics to get an answer without too much complicated mathematical calculations ?

Answer (score 11):

Let $\,x=a+b+c+d\,$ then:

$$ab+c+d=ab\color{red}{-a-b+1-1+a+b}+c+d=(a-1)(b-1)-1+x\,$$

The system can then be written as:

$$
\begin{cases}
   (a-1)(b-1)=16-x
\\ (b-1)(c-1)=25-x
\\ (c-1)(d-1)=43-x
\\ (d-1)(a-1)=14-x
\end{cases}
$$

It follows that:

$$
(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1) \;=\; (16-x)(43-x) \;=\; (25-x)(14-x)
$$

The latter equality gives $\,2\left(169 - 10 x\right) = 0\,$.

Answer (score 3):

Playing around with the four LHSs, I tried to obtain polynomials with some symmetry. I first noted that
$$\left((ab+c+d)+(cd+a+b)\right)-\left((bc+d+a)+(da+b+c)\right)=(b-d)(a-c)$$
then after replacing the $+$ sign with $\cdot$, we get
$$(ab+c+d)\cdot(cd+a+b)-(bc+d+a)\cdot(da+b+c)=(b-d)(a-c)(a+b+d+c-1).$$
Putting all together,
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{(ab+c+d)(cd+a+b)-(bc+d+a)(da+b+c)}{(ab+c+d)+(cd+a+b)-(bc+d+a)-(da+b+c)}\\&\qquad=
\frac{(b-d)(a-c)(a+b+d+c-1)}{(b-d)(a-c)}=a+b+c+d-1.
\end{align}$$
Hence with the given values we find
$$a+b+c+d=1+\frac{15\cdot 42-24\cdot 13}{15+42-24-13}=1+\frac{318}{20}=\frac{169}{10}.$$

Comment: Was there a motivation for that calculation (other than hoping that it works out)?

Comment: @CalvinLin Please see my edit.